# Ignore HTML tags in saved data while searching MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've searched too much for this and I found couple of results but non of them worked.
I'm using a MySQL query to search title and content in my posts table. My issue is that data are saved using TinyMCE which contains HTML tags. I want my search query to ignore HTML tags to not return any irrelevant results.
My query:

```
SELECT posts.id, posts.title, posts.date, posts.tags, posts.image, users.name, users.screen_name, users.id as user_id,
    IF(
        posts.title LIKE '$searchTerm%',  20, 
        IF(posts.title LIKE '%$searchTerm%', 10, 0)
    )
    + IF(posts.post LIKE '%$searchTerm%', 5,  0)
    AS weight
FROM posts
LEFT JOIN users ON posts.user_id=users.id
WHERE (
    posts.title LIKE '%$searchTerm%' 
    OR posts.post LIKE '%$searchTerm%'
)
ORDER BY weight DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Define "ignore HTML tags".  Can you give examples of what you are trying to ignore?  What happens if I'm deliberately searching for links?  Note that just echoing HTML content is likely to be a security issue for your site...

Comment: The HTML is output from TinyMCE text editor. I want to search text only. For an example TinyMCE would output "TEST TEXT" as "<p>TEST TEXT</p>". At the moment if I searched for "p" it will return this result so that I want my search query to ignore any HTML tags stored in MySQL so if I searched for "p" it return nothing but if I searched for "TEST" it return this result

Comment: ...then you need to hook up some sort of XML/HTML parser, so you can strip the tags.  Regex isn't a good fit for parsing, and the basic abilities provided by `LIKE` are even worse.  Most RDBMSs have libraries/addons for this, probably MySQL does too.

Answer (score 0):

There is a php function can do this

```
strip_tags($text);
```

You can find more information here http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

If you still want to do this in mysql , you have to define your own function

```
delimiter ||
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS strip_tags||
CREATE FUNCTION strip_tags( x longtext) RETURNS longtext
LANGUAGE SQL NOT DETERMINISTIC READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
DECLARE sstart INT UNSIGNED;
DECLARE ends INT UNSIGNED;
SET sstart = LOCATE('<', x, 1);
REPEAT
SET ends = LOCATE('>', x, sstart);
SET x = CONCAT(SUBSTRING( x, 1 ,sstart -1) ,SUBSTRING(x, ends +1 )) ;
SET sstart = LOCATE('<', x, 1);
UNTIL sstart < 1 END REPEAT;
return x;
END;
||
delimiter ;
```

Call the function in your search query after you define the function

```
$q="CALL strip_tags(SELECT textarea FROM table where ....)"
```